# Python: Using Multiple Variables in WRDS CRSP Query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, wrds

I would like to use multiple variables within a WRDS SQL query.
I am seeking to search the CRSP database by PERMNO and Date, return the stock price for a particular company on a particular day. I have a large DataFrame from which these variables will be retrieved and used to search the CRSP database.

IN:

```
sql_query = """
 SELECT cusip, permno, date, prc
 FROM crsp_a_stock.dsf
 WHERE permno = 12490
 AND date in %(dates)s
 LIMIT 100
 """
 parm = {'dates': tuple([line for line in open('dates.txt', 'r')])}

 df = db.raw_sql(sql_query,  params=parm)
 df
```

OUT:

```
    cusip       permno   date       prc
0   45920010    12490.0 1996-01-31  108.5
```

This outputs the data for IBM (PERMNO 12490) on the 31/01/1996 as desired. My issue is that I also want to be able to make the permno condition link to a variable, this way I can run the query and retrieve price data for each company on a specific day.

This code is based on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100474/using-python-dict-values-from-external-file-in-wrds-crsp-query).

Is this possible to do through db.raw_sql?
I have searched the [WRDS Help Site](https://wrds-www.wharton.upenn.edu/pages/support/programming-wrds/programming-python/querying-wrds-data-python/) (specifically the Passing Parameters to SQL section) but have been unable to solve this problem.
I am not fussed as to the specifics of the solution (such as using the .txt input file instead of a data frame), I just need to be able to implement variables for multiple WHERE conditions.
If it is not possible through db.raw_sql, are there any alternate ways to access the WRDS database through Python that would allow this?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.